# Customising the views content template

Tags: views

This is all fairly new to me so I hope i've worded the question correctly.

So I have created a view which outputs a list of news posts, which you can then click on a news post and view the contents of that post. However I've modified the styling of the listings page using the different fields etc. Now I would like to modify the content of the selected news post.

I've created a new template in my templates directory called `'views-views.tpl.php'` but that seems to override the content for the listing view landing page as well as the content.

Do I need to use a different template?

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be mostly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: IIUC you want to [modify the _node_ template](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656#node-suggestion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step:1 : You have to choose the format
 [Step:1 For this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5orW.png)

Step:2: Click the **Advanced** link and go to theme:information
 [Step:2 For this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5orW.png)

Step:3 Choose the style output templete like : [Step:3 For this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5orW.png)

Step:4 Add tpl file and write your css and all. Rescan the templete files and save it..

I choose the style format like HTML List. So I Can wrote codings like this format:[Codings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5orW.png)

Comment: This has overwritten the listing page, not the content page. So when I click on a news post, nothing has changed. I want to be able to edit the content on the content page, not the listings page.

Comment: U have to take views for that content and add the edit link field. So you will click the edit button means content will show.. So you can easily edit the content and save it.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean edit the content itself. I mean I want to customise the news content template.

Comment: Add the file like "page--news.tpl.php". Then clear the cache .I think it will help to u

Comment: For some reason when I used views-view--news--page.tpl.php it just overrides the listing page. I'll try a couple more templates, but not having much luck at the moment. Thanks.